# JavaScript - identifying the dragged element without an id

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I would like to use drag & drop to clone elements.

Most samples, including that at Mozilla, assume that the element you’re dragging has an `id`, which you can then use to clone it. You then pass this `id` on using the `dataTransfer` object. However, this has limited scalability, since you need to have a unique `id` for each element.

Is there a way to pass the dragged element on without using an `id`?

```js
var droppable = document.querySelectorAll('.droppable');
var draggable = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable');

draggable.forEach(target=>{
  target.setAttribute('draggable','true');
  target.addEventListener('dragstart',dragStart);
});


droppable.forEach(target=>{
  target.addEventListener('dragover',dragOver);
  target.addEventListener('drop',dragDrop,true);

});

function dragOver(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
function dragStart(event) {
  console.log('Drag Start');
  //  event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain',event.target.id);
}

function dragDrop(event) {
  console.log('Drag Drop');
  //  let id = event.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
  //  let element = document.querySelector(`#${id}`).cloneNode();
  //  event.currentTarget.appendChild(element);
}
```

```css
div#from, div.droppable {
  border: thin solid #666;
  min-height: 12em;
}
```

```html
  <div id="from">
    <img class="draggable" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1a/Harpo_Marx_playing_the_harp_%28cropped%29.jpeg" width="120">
  </div>
  <div class="droppable"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The ID is only being used here to select the element later so that it can be cloned:

```
let element = document.querySelector(`#${id}`).cloneNode();
```

The ID isn't needed - any unique string that can be used to identify a particular element would work. For example, if the draggable elements are all `.draggable`, a string you could use would be the index of the dragged element.

```js
var droppable = document.querySelectorAll('.droppable');
// turn from NodeList into array so that .indexOf can be called on it
const draggable = [...document.querySelectorAll('.draggable')];

draggable.forEach(target=>{
  target.setAttribute('draggable','true');
  target.addEventListener('dragstart',dragStart);
});


droppable.forEach(target=>{
  target.addEventListener('dragover',dragOver);
  target.addEventListener('drop',dragDrop,true);

});

function dragOver(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
function dragStart(event) {
  console.log('Drag Start');
  event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', draggable.indexOf(event.target));
}

function dragDrop(event) {
  console.log('Drag Drop');
  const index = event.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
  const element = draggable[index].cloneNode();
  event.currentTarget.appendChild(element);
}
```

```css
div#from, div.droppable {
  border: thin solid #666;
  min-height: 12em;
}
```

```html
<div id="from">
    <img class="draggable" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1a/Harpo_Marx_playing_the_harp_%28cropped%29.jpeg" width="120">
  </div>
  <div class="droppable"></div>
```

If you're in a situation where that approach doesn't work and you can't count on having a unique string you can associate with an element, another option would be to just assign the dragged element to an outer variable instead of trying to transfer the data through the event, which would be more straightforward anyway.

```js
var droppable = document.querySelectorAll('.droppable');
const draggable = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable');

draggable.forEach(target=>{
  target.setAttribute('draggable','true');
  target.addEventListener('dragstart',dragStart);
});


droppable.forEach(target=>{
  target.addEventListener('dragover',dragOver);
  target.addEventListener('drop',dragDrop,true);

});

function dragOver(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
let dragged;
function dragStart(event) {
  console.log('Drag Start');
  dragged = event.target;
}

function dragDrop(event) {
  console.log('Drag Drop');
  event.currentTarget.appendChild(dragged.cloneNode());
}
```

```css
div#from, div.droppable {
  border: thin solid #666;
  min-height: 12em;
}
```

```html
<div id="from">
    <img class="draggable" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1a/Harpo_Marx_playing_the_harp_%28cropped%29.jpeg" width="120">
  </div>
  <div class="droppable"></div>
```

Comment: You might want to give a tiny reason for spreading draggable to array and not droppable (to use indexOf later)

Comment: That does the job, but that requires keeping the array in either a global or closure variable. It seems to me that if I need such a variable, I could just as well put the dragged element into its own variable: `var dragged; function dragStart(event) { dragged = event.target; }` and `function dragDrop(event) { var element = dragged.cloneNode(); }` etc.

Comment: @Manngo Yeah, that's what the second snippet shows. The first snippet is there to show how you might transfer the data over the event if you wanted minimal modifications to the original technique, but - as said in the answer - it's slightly convoluted, and using an outside variable to hold the element is easier.

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t notice your second snippet. I’ve upvoted, but I think there might be an alternative approach. See my own answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `dataTransfer` object is lacking somewhat in flexibility, but I have got something working with a random attribute value:

```js
draggable.forEach(target=>{
    target.setAttribute('data-id',Math.random());
    //  etc
});

function dragStart(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain',event.target.getAttribute('data-id'));
    //  etc
}
function dragDrop(event) {
    let id = event.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
    let element = document.querySelector(`[data-id="${id}"]`).cloneNode();
    //  etc
}
```

This feels a little bit contrived, but it is the closest I can think of to the standard approach without requiring an actual `id`.